# entity manager not defined in sonata bundle

Tags: symfony, sonata-admin

I have integrated sonata admin bundle. I then integrate sonata news bundle successfully . Then I created a custom bundle. I want to configure this bundle as my CMS bundle using sonata bundle. I am able to display my CMS bundle in admin section but when I try to to edit or add new item I am getting an error:

> No entity manager defined for class Fcse\CmsBundle\Entity\Book 500
>
> Internal Server Error - RuntimeException

Book is my entity  when i run command

```
app/console doctrine:schema:update --force
```

Book table is also not creating. Am I missing something in configuration?

my config file is large. i am posting the code of my cms bundle.

```
fcse_cms:
    title:        Sonata Project
    link:         http://local.demo
    description:  Cool bundles on top of Symfony2
    salt:         'secureToken'
    class:
       book:       Fcse\CmsBundle\Entity\Book
  
    admin:
        book:
            class:       Fcse\CmsBundle\Admin\BookAdmin
            controller:  SonataAdminBundle:CRUD
            translation: CmsBundle
      
doctrine:
    orm:
        entity_managers:
            default:
                #metadata_cache_driver: apc
                #query_cache_driver: apc
                #result_cache_driver: apc
                mappings:
                     FcseCmsBundle: ~
```

and i import this file in app/config.yml.

Comment: it is configuration problem . and there are so many files . i need to know which part of code should i give

Comment: app/config.yml and in which bundle is your entity ?

Comment: And what about app/AppKernel.php ?